# Oracle update command not working

Tags: c#, oracle

I tried below code,

```
ora.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand() ;

cmd.Connection= ora;

cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmd.CommandText = "update test set name= :name";
OracleParameter name = new OracleParameter("name", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
cmd.BindByName = true; 
name.Value = "test";
cmd.Parameters.Add(a);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

ExecuteNonQuery does not work and no errors. What's wrong?
I work with Visual Studio 2012 and Oracle Express 11g

Comment: Why do you create a parameter named _name_ and then add a parameter named _a_ (where does this come from?)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a parameter named `a` instead the one you've created. Try this:

```
ora.Open();
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
{
   cmd.Connection = ora;
   cmd.BindByName = true; 

   cmd.CommandText = "update test set name = :name";
   OracleParameter name = new OracleParameter("name", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
   name.Value = "test";
   cmd.Parameters.Add(name); // add the name parameter, not "a" object.

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. With an insert command it's fine but with update when execute ExecuteNonQuery not advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the Prepare function?

try adding
`cmd.Prepare();` just after `cmd.Parameters.Add(name);`